# When is HTTP Date response header determined?

Tags: http, http-headers

Does the `Date` header represent the moment when the server started processing the request, or the moment it started sending response back? Does it depend on situations or platforms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[From the source:](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-7.1.1.2)

> When a Date header field is generated, the sender SHOULD generate its
> field value as the best available approximation of the date and time
> of message generation.  In theory, the date ought to represent the
> moment just before the payload is generated.  In practice, the date
> can be generated at any time during message origination.

Comment: IMO this is still not clear. "date and time of message generation" - message generation takes time.  "the moment just before the payload is generated" - payload could suggest that it is talking about when the message starts being put onto the wire, which is often after the message is fully generated.

Comment: It looks like Apache httpd, when not proxying, uses the "request_time" based on https://github.com/apache/httpd/blob/88afb529ab8db358cbb5b9dd84744772a727876d/server/protocol.c#L2249C18-L2249C45  "request_time" is described as "Time when the request started".  I havent built a test to confirm this.

Comment: A very quick black box test using CGI with Apache, it returns a Date of the time it gave control to the CGI, not detecting when the CGI starts writing to the stream.  Due to the one second granularity of the Date, it is very likely that this Date was the time that apache received the request.